# Using hooks in nested functions

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to rewrite a React class component into a functional hooks-based component, but i cannot figure out how to do it. The component logic and JSX looks something like this:

```
export class LeftPanel extends React.Component<ILeftPanelProps, ILeftPanelState> {

const [menuItemsFullList, setMenuItemsFullList] = useState([{links: []}] as any[]);

useEffect(() => {
    const { links } = props;

    setMenuItemsFullList(links);
}, props.links);
....

return (<>
        <SearchBox
            onChange={_onSearch}
            onClear={_onClearSearchBox}
        />
            <NavList
                listEntries={[menuItems]}
            />
</>)
```

Where the function i'm currently rewriting is onClearSearchBox:

```
private _onClearSearchBox() {
    this.setState({ menuItems: { ...this.state.menuItemsFullList } });
}
```

I tried naively rewriting it using hooks which turned the setState into this:

```
function onClearSearchBox() {
     useEffect(() => setMenuItems(menuItemsFullList));
}
```

This does not work and i do not know how to restructure the code, as i cannot call hooks inside a non-React component function. Moving it into the React component function as an inner function does not work either.

The error message i'm getting is:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be
>   called inside of the body of a function component...

I believe my mindset is still stuck to the class-based structure, as i cannot figure out how i would go about and refactoring the LeftPanel. How should i go about refactoring _onClearSearchBox to make it work with hooks?

Comment: You cannot use hooks within a class component, use a functional component instead.

Comment: Yes that is the whole point of this post. Please read what i'm actually writing

Comment: you cannot call hooks within a method or a function within the component, It has to be declared at the top level.

Comment: Yes i know. But the Searchbox component requires a function to use when user clicks on the X mark. I have to feed it a function. And previously that function was just a setState that reset the item list. This does not work with hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) is the wrong hook for this, from the docs:

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of useEffect Hook as `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` combined.

In your example, you need control over when to want to call the code e.g. on a button click. I'd say [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) would be the most appropriate hook here:

```
const onClearSearchbox = useCallback(() => {
  setMenuItemsFullList(props.items);
}, [props.items]);
...
<SearchBox onClear={onClearSearchBox} ... />
```